# Select DatePicker Date

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a feature in a silverlight applicateion where the user can start typing a date in a DatePicker as soon the DatePicker control get focus, without having to delete the date already displayed in the control. My question is how can I select the displayed date in the DatePicker when the control receives focus, something like SelectAll() for a TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

you could derive from DatePicker and get a reference to its TextBox part in OnApplyTemplate(). Whenever the TextBoxes GotFocus event occurs just SelectAll() text in the TextBox. Like so:

```
public class SelectOnFocusDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    private DatePickerTextBox _TextBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _TextBox = (DatePickerTextBox)GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox");
        if (_TextBox != null)
            _TextBox.GotFocus += (s, e) => _TextBox.SelectAll();
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

HTH.